# Emacs and Evil-mode. Issue with indentation when Copy and Paste a line

Tags: emacs, indentation, evil-mode

Thank you very much in advance for helping!

I'm a happy user of Emacs and Evil-mode (vim emulation).
I love it, but there is something that really annoys me.
Say I have the following text:

....This is the first line

....This is the second line

....This is the third line

The dots represents spaces (no tabs).
So now I'd like to copy the fist line and paste it after the third line, I'd type:

- Put the cursor anywhere in the first line.
- 'yy' (copy) or Y
- 'jj' (move the cursor down two lines)
- 'p' (paste underneath the current line)

This is the result:

....This is the first line

....This is the second line

....This is the third line

........This is the first line

The problem is that when I copy the first line, I think I copy the white spaces as well.
So when I paste it underneath, the automatic indentation paste the new line after 4 spaces.

Anyone has come across the same problem? :-)

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was fixed in this [update](https://bitbucket.org/lyro/evil/changeset/e298aab52214)

It was an EVIL bug. Something in the function evil-yank-characters.
After updating to the latest version I haven't experienced this problem any more.

Cheers